# iphone simulator only shows the background images not the labels and text box, why is this?

Tags: ios, swift, imageview

This is a simple iOS mobile app exercise. I have a image as a background, and then the labels and text box are added. I run the simulator and it shows correctly. but after a while I run the simulator again, the simulator only shows the background image, the text box and labels are not there anymore. I restart writing everything many time and the same thing happen at some point. This is driving me crazy. Did anyone know what is going on here??? Thank you so much in advance for your help!!!

Comment: Please share some code to revise

Comment: As @bandis Dave suggest your background image cover your textfiled and label please set as par his answer suggest.

Comment: @Nitin Gohel
How can I reset objects in the correct order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you done with story board than your object must be in right order.

Right/Proper Way

[image]

Wrong Way

[image]

Comment: Hi Dave, thank you so much for answering my question. I added the background image as imageview first, and then draged labels,buttons on top of it. What did I do that cause the order messed up? How should I adjust the order so the labels,buttons will show? Thank you for showing me the picture, how did you get that sort of view in xcode? I am using xcode6.3. Thanks again!

Comment: there is no any kind of sorting method in xcode..you have to arrange this views manually...if my answer could solve your problem than please make it right so other user can follow the same...thank you.

Comment: Hi @Bandish Dave, your suggest indeed solved my problem. Thank you so much!

Comment: enjoy...and best of luck for your app. @Pei

Answer (score 1):

I supposed you drag all `button`, `label`,`text box` objects in the `storyboard`. All the thing are supposed to disappear if you do not used any `Layout` stuff. Please try `AutoLayout`.

Or if you write the code to show your `label` in `viewDidLoad()`, please add the objects to your subview as `self.view.addSubview(yourObjects)`.

Comment: Hi Ethan, thank you so for answering my question. Yes, I do drag the buttons and lables on to the story board. (I add the background image as imageview first, and then drag labels on top of it) I set constrains to my labels and buttons, is it part of autolayout?

Comment: Yes, constrains you said are the AutoLayout. Because when I new to storyboard, I just dragged the objects to the view, instead of considering the the Layout setting, which lead to no thing showed on my simulator.

Comment: In my opinion, the `AutoLayout` is used to handle the problem of multi device screens.